# Independence vs correlation in stochastic vol models

Tags: stochastic-volatility, local-volatility

I am struggling a bit with some basic stuff lately:

Consider a SV model
\begin{align}
dS_t &= \sigma_t S_t dW_t \\
d\sigma_t &= b(\sigma_t,t) dZ_t
\end{align}
with $dW_t dZ_t = 0$.

I know that zero correlation does not imply independence, and in fact $S_t$ is clearly not independent of $\sigma_t$.

However, I cannot see from the above SDEs how $\sigma_t$ can depend on $S_t$, in fact I think it doesn't.

But if $\sigma_t$ were independent of $S_t$, then the local volatility function
$$
LV(K,T) := E_t [ \sigma^2_T | S_T = K] = E_t [ \sigma^2_T]
$$
would not depend on $K$. But this would imply a flat local vol function which doesn't make sense.

What is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: There is dependence because the volatility process affects the dispersion of $S_t$. Note that $\sigma_t$ is a persistent process and that $S_t=S_0+\int_0^tS_s\sigma_sdW_s$. If $\sigma_t$ is high you would expect $Var(S_t)$ to be high.

Comment: But I am asking about the (in)dependence of the vol process on the spot.

Comment: Consider the special case $b=0$. This is then a constant vol process. According to your reasoning them the constant would depend on $S$, but then it's not a constant.

Comment: I agree there are special cases when this doesn't work but that would one way to understand how they could be dependent.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I know that $S$ depends on $\sigma$, but does $\sigma$ depend on $S$, and if so how?

Comment: Those two processes are dependent in the sense that knowing the value of $S_t$ gives information about $\sigma_t$. Your intuitive notion of (in)dependence does not coincide with its mathematical definition.

Comment: @fes Sorry I still do not understand. Perhaps if you know the answer you can write it as an answer with the necessary maths so that I can wrap my head arouns this.

Comment: @Fridos Rolloos: $S_t $ depends on $\sigma_t$ which you agree with. But, based on the second equation,  The change in $\sigma_t$ depends on $b(\sigma_t, t)$ so it depends on $S_t$. Does that help ?

Comment: @markleeds I'm starting to feel very thick :) but $b$ is not a function of $S$, so how can the change in vol depend on (the change) in $S$?

Comment: Per the model, there is no formulistic dependence of $\sigma_t$ on $S_t$, but $S_t$ depends on $\sigma_t$. From a Bayesian standpoint, though, the distribution of $\Delta S_t$ yields information for the distribution of $\sigma_t$

Comment: @Frido: I feel thick all the time so don't worry about it. This is the way I would think about it. ( don't know if it's the best way ).  $\sigma_t$ doesn't depend on $S_t$ DIRECTLY but their values are correlated because the change in $S_t$ depends on $\sigma_t$ and the change in $\sigma_t$ depends on $b$ which is a function of $\sigma_t$. Therefore, somewhat intuitively, ( although I hate that term ), the change in $\sigma_t$ depends on the change in $S_t$. So, if the change in the two variables depend on each other, then the levels of the variables depend on each other. I hope that helps ?

Comment: @Frido: I think Fes's answer is great because he doesn't even involve the second equation. So, to simplify his explanation: When $\sigma_t$ is larger, the change in $S_t$ will generally be larger. Therefore, everything else remaining constant, $\sigma_t$ should be expected to be greater,  the greater the value of the change in $S_t$. But the the value of the change in $S_t$ should be positively correlated with the value of $S_t$ as as long as $\sigma_t$ is not going back and forth in different directions in a volatile way. I think the latter is what fes means by persistence.

Comment: @markleeds I think I am starting to see Fes' answer, because, $$\log S_T/S_t = -\frac12 \int_t^T \sigma_u^2 du + \int_t^T \sigma_u dW_u$$. The trouble I am having is expressing the instantaneous vol at time $T$ (not just the integrated variance) in terms of $S_T$ to confirm indeed the dependence.

Comment: @markleeds Got it, thank you. I think I may have fallen in the independence vs causality trap here.

Comment: Frido:  The $\sigma$ is always subscripted by $t$ so things always depend on its previous value of it also. So, when fes describes the dependence, he is making the assumption that $\sigma_t$ and $\sigma_{t+ \delta}$ for $\delta > 0$ are positively autocorrelated. Otherwise, $\sigma_t$ can be due to positive drift ( of $S_t$ )  at one instant and then negative drift ( of $S_t$ ) at another which isn't usually the case. Usually, volatility exhibits positive autocorrelation in terms of the direction it is pushing $S_t$. This is called volatility clustering in the literature.

Comment: I'm glad you got it ( I hope I got it !!!! ).  Thanks to fes for his enlightening explanation and avoiding the use of the second equation; the inclusion of which made things more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the random variables $S_t$ and $\sigma_t$. Let their marginal cumulative distribution functions be $F_{S,t}$ and $F_{\sigma,t}$. The variables are said to be independent if their joint distribution function satisfies
$F_{S,\sigma,t}=F_{S,t}F_{\sigma,t}$. Independence is naturally symmetric. The best way to think about it intuitively is that knowing the value of one random variable gives no information about the other variable. Note that dependence between the random variables might not be in any sense causal.

Without specifying $b$ in your example it is difficult to formally prove independence/dependence. However, when $\sigma_t$ is persistent (autocorrelated), since $S_t=S_0+\int_0^{t}\sigma_sS_sdW_s$ you would expect high values of $\sigma_t$ to increase the dispersion of $S_t$, i.e. make observing extreme values of $S_t$ more likely. Alternatively, a high value of $\sigma_t$ is more likely when $S_t$ takes a value in the tails. Therefore you would not expect these two processes to generally be independent.

Comment: How do you define “persistence”?

Comment: @Daneel Olivaw I meant autocorrelated.

Comment: +1 Thanks, haven't accepted it yet (hope you don't mind). Let me think abt it a bit more and see also what others answer if any.

Comment: @FridoRolloos Sure take your time:)

Comment: I suspect that the fact that $$\log S_T/S_t = -\frac12 \int_t^T \sigma^2_u du + \int_t^T \sigma_u dW_u$$ at least shows that the integrated variance depends on among others $S_T$. Is there a way to show a similar relationship between $S_T$ and $\sigma_T$? Because that is I think what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Yes from that formula you can see that $S_T$ depends on $\int_{t}^{T}\sigma_udW_u$. Now $S_T$ depends on $\sigma_T$ e..g when $\int_{t}^{T}\sigma_udW_u$ depends on $\sigma_T$, which you would typically expect to be true but might require some regularity condition on $b()$. Intuitively it is true if $\sigma_t$ is persistent, i.e. $Corr(\sigma_T,\sigma_t)>0$.